# how to resume a for loop at the last iteration if system breaks (python)?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, deep-learning, resuming-training

I am very new to python. In fact i am working on deep learning and trying to train my network.

Due to the large size of the database the system crashes so often.

I am trying to find a solution which enables me to resume the program at the last iteration (where it has crashed) without having to restart all the training over.

Comment: It's really hard to give a generic answer, so I'll say this:  the first thing that comes to mind is that you could serialize the state of your learner (neural network or whatever model you're using) at the end of each loop. Then deserialize and resume, in the even of a DB crash

Comment: you could create a counter variable and create an `atexit` function to write the counter to a file in the event of an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [finally](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) block that will always run, but saving and recovering data depends on your implementation:

```
try:
    <recover if applicable>
    train()
except Exception as e:
    <handle a known case here>
finally:
    <always save your data>
```